# Image not loading in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
I am trying to flip images whenever user clicks the next button on the web page
Refer https://jsfiddle.net/jonathan668/vwc1hd8z/6/ 

Issue is My image urls generated via javascript are not loading to html
```

I tried various options but unable to resolve

I am new to Javascript and CSS also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new `Image` object to change the source. Remove line 8 of your JavaScript `image5 = new Image();` and it should work perfectly.